# How to get the first match from the regex find all function?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, list, output

I am new to regex and python, I have to find a keyword from a text file and after successful finding the string I have to find the only number from the string. But the number is getting printed 6 times. I only need the first outcome to store in a variable as integer. Here is my full code. And the string I am looking for from the .txt file is "Lost\n7". And the number I want from this string is 7.

```
import re
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:

        # Capture one-or-more characters of non-whitespace after the initial match
        # rsrp = re.search(r'RSRP:(\S+)', line)


        packet_loss_search = re.search(r'Lost(\S+)',line)


        # Did we find a match?
        if (packet_loss_search):
            # Yes, process it
            details = packet_loss_search.group(0)
            a=str(details)

            #a=a[-1]
            #print(a)
            temp =re.findall(r'\d+', a)
            res = list(map(int, temp))

            print(res[0])
```

OUTPUT:

```
7
7
7
7
7
7
```

Comment: Try `with open('test.txt') as f: print( re.search(r'Lost\n(\d+)', f.read()).group(1) )`

Comment: Break out of the loop when you find a match.

Comment: Why do you use `findall()` if you only want the first match?

Comment: If my answer did not solve your problem please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest reading the file into memory as a single string if your expected match(es) span(s) across multiple lines. You could fix the code by replacing it with

```py
import re
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    m = re.search(r'Lost\n(\d+)', f.read())
    if m: # Check if there is a match
        print(m.group(1))
```

Here, `f.read()` will read the file contents into a single string, and `Lost\n(\d+)` will match and capture into Group 1 any one or more digits after `Lost` + a newline char.

Comment: "the process finished with exit code 0" I tried the "Lost\n(\d+)" before but it does not print anything as if it detects null or space. But in .txt file the exact string is "\n2866\nLost\n7 (0.24 %)". Where I need to find the 7 as a integer.

Comment: @swarnendupanja If the text file shows `\n` (not a line break), then you need `m = re.search(r'Lost\\n(\d+)', f.read())`

Comment: Thank You so much @Wiktor . You solved my problem. Learnt something new today. Thanks again.